# static page pagination not working

Tags: php, pagination

I have a static home page on my Wordpress blog and I cannot seem to figure this out.

I want to be able to navigate between different pages in my blog via the pagination.

I changed 'paged' to 'page' as I have seen that you should use 'page' for static home pages.

However, when I click page 2 or 3, the page reloads and refreshes the home page. It doesn't go to the next page like I need it to.

This was already built into the theme, but for some reason it just won't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
/**
 * Set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page).
 *
 * @var int $paged
 */

    '<?php
    $mb_theme_options = maicha_blog_theme_options();
    $mid_post_category = $mb_theme_options['mid_post_category'];
    $story_layout = $mb_theme_options['story_layout'];
    $sidebar_position = $mb_theme_options['sidebar_option'];
    $mid_post_title = $mb_theme_options['mid_post_title'];
    $mid_checkbox = $mb_theme_options['mid_checkbox'];
    $mid_post_break = $mb_theme_options['mid_post_break'];
    
    if (is_page_template('page-templates/homepage.php') && $mid_checkbox== '1'){
    if($mid_post_category && 'none' != $mid_post_category){
        $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ) ? intval( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) : 1;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => $mid_post_break,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'desc',
            'page' => $paged,
            'orderby' => 'menu_order date',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( $mid_post_category ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
    else{
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'desc',
            'orderby' => 'menu_order date',
        );
    }
    
    $total_pages = $featured->max_num_pages;
                                if ($total_pages > 1){
    
                                    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('page'));
                                    echo '<div class="navigation">';
    
                                    echo paginate_links(array(
                                        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                                        'format' => '?page=%#%',
                                        'current' => $current_page,
                                        'total' => $total_pages,
                                        'type'      => 'list',
                                        'prev_text'          => esc_html__('Previous Posts','maicha-blog'),
                                        'next_text'          => esc_html__('More Posts','maicha-blog'),
                                    ));
                                    echo '</div>';
                                }
                                wp_reset_postdata();
    
                            }
    
                            ?>'
```

Comment: If you want paginated posts in the homepage, then why are you using a static homepage? The latest posts option is specifically for this.

Comment: My homepage has 3 sections: the first thing is a big image carousel that displays the 3 top posts, the next thing is a smaller different kind of image carousel that displays a specific category of posts, and the third thing is a list of my most recent blogs with a pagination underneath of it. ideally I really only want the pagination to be used for mobile (because the image carousels bog down my mobile site speed). maybe the resolution is using "the latest posts option" for my homepage for just mobile? is that possible?

Comment: the theme is setup to where if I don't use the static homepage, then I don't get the image carousels that come with the theme, which I'd like to keep for the desktop version of my site. if I could do the latest posts option for just mobile, that would be ideal.